# How to implement swagger documentation for .html request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

We have a Spring MVC application in which we are loading a jsp page. Is it possible to document the call using Swagger ? This is not a REST call. A normal spring mvc call.
Below is the reference for the call

```
@RequestMapping("/dashboard.htm")
    public String dashboard(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, HttpSession session , HttpServletResponse response) {

    // code here

    }
```

Is it possible to document this call using swagger ?